# Coffeescript add button on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Thats my Setup:

```
<header class="shop-banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5jSh4fI.jpg" style="height: 250px" class="prf_cover">
    <!-- when user hovers -->
    <%= link_to "Edit Cover", edit_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-custom prf_cvr_edt" %>
  </header>
```

I need upon hovering over the image, the button to appear.

I tried with

```
jQuery ->
  jQuery(".prf_cvr_edt").hide()
  jQuery(".prf_cover").hover (->
    jQuery(this).find(".prf_cvr_edt").fadeIn 1
  ), ->
    jQuery(this).find(".prf_cvr_edt").fadeOut 1
```

as this hides the button, but does not fade it in upon hovering. I need the code in coffeescript.

Any helping hand still awake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it.. was actually pretty simple..

i moved the class `prf_cover` to the `shop-banner` and my coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('.prf_cvr_edt').hide()
  $('.prf_cover').hover(
    -> $(this).find('.prf_cvr_edt').fadeIn(400)
    -> $(this).find('.prf_cvr_edt').fadeOut(200)
  )
```

Comment: It wasn't working because you were looking for the `.prf_cvr_edt` class inside the image tag which doesn't exist.

Comment: Glad you found your answer. If you want to tidy up the syntax a tad, you can remove the parenthesis from your `.hover`. So long as the anonymous inner function declarations are indented properly, coffeescript should render it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Easier yet, leave out the `find`, because it's not doing what you think it is:

```
$ ->
  $('.prf_cvr_edt').hide()
  $('.prf_cover').hover(
    -> $('.prf_cvr_edt').fadeIn(400)
    -> $('.prf_cvr_edt').fadeOut(200)
  )
```

`find` looks for *descendants*, which the link isn't, because your image tag closes itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not strictly required that JavaScript is used you should try out CSS, it has the additional benefit of being hardware accelerated. Using your current HTML structure something like this should work:

```
.prf_cvr_edt {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
.prf_cover:hover + .prf_cvr_edt {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/8796194